# UIImage not showing in UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiimage, swift4

I have added some UIImage to my iOS app and wanted to show them in my custom UITableViewCell.  There would be different images depending on what track is selected.  So in my model, I have created the following code which is a switch statement.

```
class GrandPrix {
let grandPrix: String!
let firstDriver: String!
let secondDriver: String!
let thirdDriver: String!
var trackIconName = ""

init(grandPrix: String, firstDriver: String, secondDriver: String, thirdDriver: String){
    self.grandPrix = grandPrix
    self.firstDriver = firstDriver
    self.secondDriver = secondDriver
    self.thirdDriver = thirdDriver
}

func updateTrackicon(grandPrix: String) -> String {
    switch (grandPrix) {
    case "Australian GP":
        return "Australian"
    case "Bahrain GP":
        return "Bahrain"
    case "Chinese GP":
        return "Chinese"
    case "Azerbaijan GP":
        return "Azerbaijan"
    case "Spanish GP":
        return "Chinese"
    case "Monaco GP":
        return "Monaco"
    case "Canadian GP":
        return "Canadian"
    case "French GP":
        return "French"
    case "Austrian GP":
        return "Austrian"
    case "British GP":
        return "British"
    case "German GP":
        return "German"
    case "Hungarian GP":
        return "Hungarian"
    case "Belgian GP":
        return "Belgian"
    case "Italian GP":
        return "Italian"
    case "Singapore GP":
        return "Singapore"
    case "Russian GP":
        return "Russian"
    case "Japanese GP":
        return "Japanese"
    case "American GP":
        return "United States"
    case "Brazilian GP":
        return "Brazilian"
    case "Abu Dhabi GP":
        return "Abu Dhabi"
    default :
        return "no track"
    }
   }
 }
```

Now in my UITableViewClass I have included the following code that will show the UIImage within the cell

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
 let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") as! GrandPrixTableViewCell
    let race = self.grandPrix[indexPath.row]
    // Configure the cell...
    cell.grandPrix.text = race.grandPrix
    cell.firstPostion.text = race.firstDriver
    cell.secondPosition.text = race.secondDriver
    cell.thirdPostion.text = race.thirdDriver
    cell.trackImage.image = UIImage(named: race.updateTrackicon(grandPrix: race.grandPrix))

    return cell
}
```

I have hooked up the cell and checked that the size of the UIImages is well within the size of the UIImage in the storyboard.  When I run the app the text appears but not the image.  Any help would be appreciated.

Below is code that explains where the array is coming from.

```
import UIKit

class PredictorTableViewController: UITableViewController {

var predictorTrack = ""
var firstDriver = ""
var secondDriver = ""
var thirdDriver = ""

var grandPrix = [GrandPrix]() { didSet {self.tableView.reloadData()} }
```

I thought about this and tried to change the `cellForRowAt indexPath` to the following code.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
 let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") as! GrandPrixTableViewCell
    let race = self.grandPrix[indexPath.row]
    // Configure the cell...
    cell.grandPrix.text = race.grandPrix
    cell.firstPostion.text = race.firstDriver
    cell.secondPosition.text = race.secondDriver
    cell.thirdPostion.text = race.thirdDriver
    race.trackIconName = race.updateTrackicon(grandPrix: race.grandPrix)
    cell.trackImage.image = UIImage(named: race.trackIconName)

    return cell
}
```

I thought this would show the Track UIImage but unfortunately, I am still not getting an image.

Comment: In the code, you've declared `grandPrix` as `String` and you are using it as `Array` in `let race = self.grandPrix[indexPath.row]`. Kindly explain.

Comment: Also, check if the image with that particular name is available in the `Assets`

Comment: I have checked the image in the ```Assets``` and have tested others.

Comment: Replace `cell.trackImage.image = UIImage(named: race.updateTrackicon(grandPrix: race.grandPrix))` by
`let image = UIImage(named: race.updateTrackicon(grandPrix: race.grandPrix));
cell.trackImage.image = image`
and set a breakpoint at the 2nd statement. Then you can check if the image exists.

Comment: I am getting the following ```image UIImage?nil none```

Comment: If the image is nil, it is probably a naming error. Check the name again with case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possibly a naming error. Confirm if the name matches or not.

Comment: I will check later tonight as I am at work now.  This is a hobby and so won’t be able to check during the day.